# api endpoint dependent on another one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im working with Mapbox and would like to show location based on coordinates of the user through their IP address. Im using two apis to accomplish that, one to get the IP address and the 2nd to get the latitude and longitude and insert in the Mapbox object state. Id like to know can I make one api call run after the 1st one is fulfilled since it returns data that will be used as a parameter in the second endpoint?

```
 const [ip, setIp] = useState("");
  const [lat, setLat] = useState("");
  const [long, setLong] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getIP();
    getGeoloc();
  }, []);

  const getIP = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
    const response = await data.json();
    setIp(response.ip);
    console.log(response.ip);
  };

  const getGeoloc = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      `http://api.ipstack.com/${ip}?access_key=${KEY}`
    );
    const response = await data.json();
    setLat(response.latitude);
    setLong(response.longitude);
    console.log(response.latitude);
    console.log(response.longitude);
  };

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: long,
    zoom: 8,
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for getIP() to finish fetching and then execute it using async () in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
     async getData() {
         await getIP();
         getGeoloc();
     }
     getData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to call the other api on the first's return:

```
const getIP = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
    const response = await data.json();
    setIp(response.ip);
    const getGeoloc = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(
            `http://api.ipstack.com/${ip}?access_key=${KEY}`
        );
        const response = await data.json();
        setLat(response.latitude);
        setLong(response.longitude);
    };
};
```

Sorry if this code is wrong, my intention was only to show the logic, I don't program in TypeScript/CoffeScript.